# Source from external Folder (linked Source) not appearing in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

i have a Air Project in which i have added three extenal source folders.
but when i reopen project or strat flash builder again i get icon on those folder like this

### [image]

but when i open the configuration for that project and try to validate the path and adding it again i get message like this

[image]

but the path is valid. proof is this pic
[image]

---

what could be possible error,,, is there any way that i when ever re-open project i get no warning and able to navigate through the linked source code. now i am doing it 
1- deleting on of the linked folder 
2- again adding that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your project files,

**.actionScriptProperties**

**.flexProperties**

**.project**

make all of them writeable. this issue occur when you get code from Visual Source Safe that the files are copied to local machine in read-only mode.

Comment: nice to hear that you, that you solved your problem.
please mark this post as anwer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

as for quick:

1. install flas builder 4.1

   2.imort that project into workspace

3rd is using maven ;)

Comment: downloading new version lets see.. is there any way that flash builder itself download updates from the web.